# How to create/delete cube partition via SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssas, cube

I ain't able to find any good tutorial which can tel me how to create/delete cube partition through SSIS tasks.

This is the first time I am doing that, in fact, I am new to SSAS too. So, the tutorial I found that is

[Creating cube partition with Script Task](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2008/09/15/ssis-create-analysis-services-partitions-from-a-ssis-package.aspx)

[Analysis Service Execute DDL Task](http://www.bidn.com/articles/ssas-administration/88/using-ssis-to-automate-the-creation-of-cube-partitions)

I have also seen **Analysis Service Processing Task** but I am not sure if it can do the same task or not.

I need to run my package every month to create new partition of a cube, based of variables.

Which method will be the best and recommended to do cube partition via SSIS ?

I want to create a new partition and to delete the old partition based on condition.

**P.S.**: I was a .NET developer before, so it Script task is the best option then I can go for it.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a template partition for each measure group of your cube. With a SSIS script task you can then access the template partition through AMO (Analysis Management Objects), clone it, modify it where necessary (e.g., the source query) and save it to your database.

Example: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2008/09/15/ssis-create-analysis-services-partitions-from-a-ssis-package.aspx